# Haskell: how to print each element of list separated with comma

Tags: list, haskell

I am trying to print list with comma.
I have list like `["1","2","3"]` and I want to print `1,2,3`
How can I do that?

I tried:

```
printList xs = mapM_ (\(a) -> do
                      putStr a
                      putStr (",")) xs
```

But I dont know how to remove the last comma.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`intercalate`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:intercalate). It'll insert the comma between each element of the list and concatenate the resulting list of strings to turn it into a single string.

```
import Data.List

toCommaSeparatedString :: [String] -> String
toCommaSeparatedString = intercalate ","

ghci> toCommaSeparatedString ["1","2","3"]
"1,2,3"
```

Answer (score 4):

This is a bit of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): as Benjamin Hodgson shows, you’re better off turning your list into a string, and *then* printing that – you want as much of your logic *outside* of the IO monad as possible.

But of course, even *if* your question is somewhat in the wrong direction from the start, it has an answer! Which is that, for example, you could write this:

```
printList :: [String] -> IO ()
printList [] = return ()
printList [x] = putStr x
printList (x:xs) = do
  putStr x
  putStr ","
  printList xs
```

Benjamin’s answer is *better*. But this one might elucidate `IO` monad code and `do`-notation a bit more.

Comment: very nice and understandable solution.